# Table Inside Bootstrap Grid Goes Beyond the Grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This might be hard to explain.

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kSMeYCHjVuXyvy9Uvkdg?p=preview

This is to mock an application that I am working on.

In `col-xs-2`, I have a side panel/menu.
In `col-xs-10`, I have a table that displays user for the data. (Btw, the word `Honorificabilitudinitatibus` is some long word that I got from wikipedia.

The problem is that because my table has too much content or the words are too long, the table is extending beyond the `row` div, which I highlighted with a red border.

I would like everything to be within the red border (or the red border to  grow as the table becomes larger). How  do I do this in bootstrap?

Thanks

Comment: from [bootstrap's site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive): "Create responsive tables by wrapping any `.table` in `.table-responsive` to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables." **edit:** The main issue is that tables don't respond well to smaller screen sizes/widths.  I'm not sure a table will do what you're needing.  Can you refactor to use `display:table` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Joseph Marikle suggests, you should look at the responsive tables feature provided with bootstrap. They have most likely worked out a lot of issues that are associated with this.

However, you can use the CSS property `table-layout` along with a 100% width to achieve this.

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: The problem with table-responsive is that it renders a scrollbar at the very bottom, making the application not user friendly. Ideally I want the whole page to scroll, not just that col-xs-10 div.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap `row` is meant to placed inside a `container` as a result it contains negative margins which are causing your table to extend beyond.

So you should place the `row` div in a `.container-fluid`...

http://bootply.com/PTS4QZHgl8

Comment: I don't think that's right. If you put the border on col-xs-10, and shrink the screen, you'll see that the table extends pass the row. see fork: http://www.bootply.com/ObiTuv0gH4

Comment: Yeah.. that's why you should place it in a `table-responsive` div